# WCF same Identity as on client?

Tags: c#, wcf, identity

For an experimenting project I'am struggling with a service. The client is an ASP.NET MVC 4 and the service will be build with WCF. For now all the systems are in a trusted subsystem so SSL/certificates is not necessarily.

The problem I'am currently dealing with is: Is het possible when I create a new GenericIdentity like:

```
IIdentity newIdentity = new GenericIdentity("Test", "Custom authentication");
string[] newRoles = { "TestRole" };
IPrincipal testPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(newIdentity, newRoles);
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = testPrincipal;
```

It is possible to have the created user when I'am on the WCF service calling the following code:

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity;
```

Or

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity;
```

Or

```
Thread.CurrentPrinicpal;
```

I get the user which I created in the client? Or do I have to write a WCF extensibility for this?

I'm currently using a WsHttpBinding and security mode Transport and clientCredentialType: Windows. Maybe something wrong about the configuration?

Comment: Have you specified NTLM auth schema on both client/wcf bindings or which authentication are you using?

Comment: When I inspect the ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity; or the ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity; on the WCF service, the VS2012 debugger sais that this authentication schema is used. But my Windows identity is shown as username, instead of the one I created with the GenericIdentity in the ASP.NET MVC 4 application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered to achieve this automatically in WCF that you must specify a certificate...

In the messages that are sent to the WCF service I created a few properties with the information in the datacontracts that is necessary to create a GenericPrinicpal (in this the username en the roles). Because I have an trusted subsystem I don't want to authenticate the user on each WCF-service (to much overhead for my scenario). [See also Trusted subsystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730288.aspx)

With this I created a WCF extension that implemented a parameter inspector and with reflection I set the credentials from the CurrentPrincipal in the specified properties of the contract. [For more information about parameter inspectors and how to apply it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647875.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

On server side (WCF), the security context will have the username value you have used to authenticate to the service.

This means, that if you have defined on client side windows authentication, WCF will find the security context filled with the username of the windows identity you used.

In order for you to authenticate to the servive with windows account, you can use the following code
on client side :

```
channelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential =
                        new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
```

Having used this code, you can access the identity on server side with the below code :

```
OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity
```

In general, try to be explicit on client side authentication info. Currently, you seem to 
be simply using the default behavior of windows authentication schema, by setting identity 
on current thread.

I hope this helps.

Comment: But it isn't possible that WCF detects this automatically?